# How can I disable the horizontal stretching/overscroll when using the `verticalScroll` modifier?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, scrollable, overscroll

I want a scrollable view which I'm doing by using the `verticalScroll` modifier on a column.

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) { 
    // ... I could provide more detail about the contents here but I don't think it matters.
}
```

When I start scrolling vertically, the view will allow horizontal over scroll and stretch the view horizontally. This doesn't seem like desirable behavior to me.

[image: Scrolling around in my view]

Is there anyway to stop this behavior from happening?

Answer (score 2):

You can try disabling the overscroll via CompositionLocal directly scoping the `Column`

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyListWithoutOverScroll() {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalOverscrollConfiguration provides null
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
            repeat(100) {
                Text("Hello World $it")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or set it in `Activity` level

```
@Composable
fun MyList() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        repeat(100) {
            Text("Hello World $it")
        }
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            CompositionLocalProvider(
                LocalOverscrollConfiguration provides null
            ) {
                MyList()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without overscroll using CompositionLocalProvider setting it to null (not-stretching)

[image]

With overscroll (stretching)

[image]